# Can a digital system that represents all integers represent all rational numbers? all real numbers?

Tags: system, digital

**Can a digital system that represents all integers represent all rational numbers? 
All real numbers?**

Comment: How could *any* system represent all integers ?

Comment: Can you get a community to answer your homework questions, whilst putting no effort in yourself?

Answer (score 1):

This is not a question for here, but:

Yes for rational numbers, both rational and integers have the same cardinality

Not know for real numbers, the cardinality of real numbers is higher than the cardinality of integers. So, there may be systems that can represent all the integers but not all the real numbers (and some will represent both).